# If $C_A(F(A)) \le F(A)$ and $C_B(F(B)) \le F(B)$, then this also holds for $AB$ if $A,B \unlhd G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $A, B \unlhd G$ be normal subgroups of a finite group $G$ such that
$$
 C_A(F(A)) \le F(A) ~\mbox{ and }~
 C_B(F(B)) \le F(B).
$$
where $F(G)$ denotes the [Fitting Subgroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitting_subgroup) of $G$. I want to show that $C_{AB}(F(AB)) \le F(AB)$.

Here what I thought might be useful, for every finite group $G$ we have
$$
 O_p(C_G(F(G)) / ( C_G(F(G)) \cap F(G)) ) = 1
$$
for each $p \in \pi(G) = \{ p \in \mathbb P : p \mid |G| \}$. And of course
$$
 C_{AB}(F(AB)) \le F(AB) \Leftrightarrow C_{AB}(F(AB)) / ( C_{AB}(F(AB)) \cap F(AB)) = 1. 
$$
So one possibility might be, using the prerequisites, that if 
$$
 C_{AB}(F(AB)) / ( C_{AB}(F(AB)) \cap F(AB)) \ne 1
$$
then there exists some $p$ such that 
$$
 O_p(C_{AB}(F(AB)) / ( C_{AB}(F(AB)) \cap F(AB))) \ne 1
$$
(for example nilpotent or solvable groups satisfy this). But here I have no idea how to establish this property?

Comment: Yes, looks less clumsy :) In my textbook they did not wrote it like that, maybe because sometimes (I saw it on the wiki article "centraliser and normaliser") people write $Z(g)$ to mean the centraliser of an element, but also $C_G(g) := C_G(\{g\})$, but by the convention $Z(U) = \{u\in U: u^v = u \forall v \in U \}$ clearly $Z(g) \ne Z(\{g\})$, anyway. Thanks for your hint, so when these non-abelian simple factors all lie in $A$ or $B$, then this contradicts $C_X(F(X)) \le F(X), X \in \{A,B\}$, so that $O_p(\ldots)$ could no contain such a min. norm. subgrp, do you mean that? I will try!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write what I meant last night. As you said yourself, $O_p(C_{AB}(F(AB))/Z(F(AB))$ must be trivial. I meant suppose that $C_{AB}(F(AB))/Z(F(AB))$ has a non-solvable minimal normal subgroup $S/Z(F(AB))$. Then $[S,AB]$ contains $[S,S]$, so it is non-solvable. Also, since all subgroups are normal, $[S,AB]=[S,A][S,B]$, so at least one of $[S,A]$ and $[S,B]$ is non-solvable, which contradicts $C_A(F(A)) \le F(A)$ or $C_B(F(B) \le F(B)$.